# If $e^{itx_n}$ converges for every $t\in\mathbb R$, then does $x_n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> **Question** : Is the following true for any real number sequence $x_n$ ?
>
> "If $e^{itx_n}$ converges for every $t\in\mathbb R$, then $x_n$ converges."
>
> Note that $i^2=-1$.

**Motivation** : We know that the converse of the above proposition is true. However, I'm facing difficulty for the above proposition. Can anyone help?

Comment: If $x_n$ are bounded, then the result is straightforward. So the question is, does the above imply that the $x_n$ are bounded?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. The above does not imply that the $x_n$ are bounded.

Comment: Do you have an example unbounded $x_n$ that satisfies the above? (I have been racking my brain on this!)

Comment: Well, unfortunately no.

Comment: Why do you assert that the above does not imply that the $x_n$ are bounded?

Comment: Hmm, I should have said "The above does not say anything about whether $x_n$ are bounded or not."

Comment: This is a curious problem indeed...

Comment: I believe the hypotheses imply that for some $\alpha$, we have, for each $t$, that $e^{itx_n} \to e^{it \alpha}$.

Comment: I wonder if my previous comment can be combined with the Lévy continuity theorem to conclude that $x_n \to \alpha$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, $x_n$ converges.

Denote 
$$f(t):=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{itx_n},\quad t\in\Bbb R.$$
Clearly $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $\Bbb R$, so by [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem),
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}e^{itx_n}dt=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)dt,\quad \forall~ t_1<t_2.$$
Note that $|f(t)|=1$, $\forall t\in\Bbb R$, so there exist $a<b$, such that
$$\int_a^bf(t)dt\ne 0\Longrightarrow \int_a^be^{itx_n}dt\ne 0 \quad\text{for large }n.$$
Then by fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$x_n=\frac{i(e^{iax_n}-e^{ibx_n})}{\int_a^be^{itx_n}dt}  \quad\text{for large }n.$$
Letting $n\to\infty$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\frac{i(f(a)-f(b))}{\int_a^bf(t)dt}.$$

Comment: +1: You can show that there is some $\alpha$ such that $f(t) = e^{i \alpha t}$, hence $x_n \to \alpha$ (using the idea of the proof in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_5).

Comment: Thank you very much! The theorem is strong indeed.

Comment: @mathlove: You are welcome!

Comment: @copper.hat: Thank you. $f(t)=e^{i\alpha t}$ is a direct corollary of $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\alpha$ in my answer.

Comment: I started with a similar proof, but instead of using the limits $a,b$ as you have done, I was using $0,t$, and kept getting stuck trying to show the resulting denominator was non-zero, so I gave up that approach. I eventually managed using the Lévy continuity theorem, but this seemed (because it  was) like using a hammer instead of a needle. Your approach is very appropriate.

Comment: @copper.hat: I believe that even dominated convergence theorem is not necessary to solve this problem, but I cannot find a simple argument at this moment.

Comment: I had to use the DCT to show that $f(t) = e^{i \alpha t}$...

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group. The dual $\hat G$ of $G$ is the group of continuous homomorphisms $G \to S^1$.

Given a real number $s$, we may define a continuous homomorphism $\varphi_s :\mathbf R \to S^1$ by $t \mapsto e^{ist}$. The map $s \mapsto \varphi_s$ is a map $\mathbf R \to \hat{\mathbf R}$. This map is an isomorphism of locally compact abelian groups.

Therefore, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges in $\mathbf R$ if and only if the sequence $\{\varphi_{x_n}\}$ converges in $\hat{\mathbf R}$ if and only if the sequence $e^{itx_n}$ converges for every $t \in \mathbf R$.