# if $e^{itx_n}$ converges for every t in a countable dense subset of $[-t0, t0]$, does $x_n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, limits

A similar question is asked here: [If $e^{itx_n}$ converges for every $t\in\mathbb R$, then does $x_n$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562506/if-eitx-n-converges-for-every-t-in-mathbb-r-then-does-x-n-converge). $\{x_n\}$ is a real valued sequence. But since my quesion arises in a probabilistic context, it is assumed here that the convergence is on a countable dense subset and the approach in the above question does not work. Any countable dense subset is enough for my purpose.

Added:
As Yuval Peres pointed out, it is not true. Actually the probability background is the following excercise: use martingale method to show $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}Y_i$ for $Y_i$ indepenent converges in distribution implies it converges almost surely. I am trying to use $e^{itS_n}/E[e^{itS_n}]$ for |t| small and i can show for each fixed t small, $e^{itS_n}$ converges a.s. How can I show ${S_n}$ converges from this?

Comment: Since you write about probabilistic context, does the "$x_{n}$"'s mean random variables?. In that case the notation is $X_{n}$ and you should also use the probability tag for the question. Please elaborate on what $x_{n}$'s are

Comment: $x_n$ is not a random variable. edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the countable dense set to be the rational numbers, and let $x_n=2\pi n!$.

**Added:** Regarding the probabilistic motivation:
Given the random variables $S_n$ on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$,
define a Borel $\times \mathcal F$ measurable set  $A \subset [-\delta,\delta] \times \Omega$ by
$$A:=\{(t,\omega):\: \exists \, \lim_n e^{itS_n}\}\,.$$
If we know that for each $t \in [-\delta,\delta]$ we have
$P(\exists \, \lim_n e^{itS_n})=1$, then by Fubini's theorem $A$ has full measure in the product space, and with probability 1,
the sequence $\{S_n\}$ has the property that $\lim_n e^{itS_n}$ exists for a.e. $t \in [-\delta,\delta]$. This suffices to apply the elegant integration argument in the first answer to [If $e^{itx_n}$ converges for every $t\in\mathbb R$, then does $x_n$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562506/if-eitx-n-converges-for-every-t-in-mathbb-r-then-does-x-n-converge) and deduce that $S_n$ converges a.s.

Comment: This counter example is very nice. Actually the probability background is the following excercise: use martingale method to show $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}Y_i$ for $Y_i$ indepenent converges in distribution implies it converges almost surely. I am trying to use $e^{itS_n}/E[e^{itS_n}]$ for $|t|$ small and i can show for each fixed $t$ small, $e^{itS_n}$ converges a.s. How can I show $S_n$ converges from this?

Comment: Thank you a lot !